# Filtrando por campos pipe

Tags: angular

esoty filtrando por campos, tengo grupos y esos grupos tienen un número

0
1
2
3
4 ...

Entonces pongo que se filtren los del grupo 1, pero me aparecen los del grupo

1,10,11,12...

alguna idea?

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { GruposComponent } from '../components/grupos/grupos.component';
@Pipe({
    name: 'filtergroup'
})
export class GruposfilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public gruposComp:GruposComponent){

    }
    transform(items:any, filterIdentificador: string, filterPersonal: string, filterPaciente: string){
        if (items && items.length){
            return items.filter(item =>{
                if (filterIdentificador && item.identificador_grupo.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterIdentificador.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (filterPersonal && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterPersonal.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }
                if (filterPaciente && item.nombre.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterPaciente.toLowerCase()) === -1){
                    return false;
                }             
                return true;
           })
        }
        else{
            return items;
        }

    }
}
```

Con este código es con lo que filtro, luego en mi HTML en el ngFor le pongo filtergroup:filterIdentificador que es el número

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé si he entendido correctamente la pregunta: entiendo que tienes un listado de grupos con un `identificador_grupo` de 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12... y que si pones un valor en el filtro solo te devuelva los grupos cuyo campo sea igual a ese valor en vez de todos los que contengan ese valor como te está ocurriendo ahora.

De ser así, el primer `if` no se ajusta a esta condición:

> `if (filterIdentificador && 
>        item.identificador_grupo.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterIdentificador.toLowerCase()) === -1){
>      return false;
>   }`

En vez de comprobar con el indexOf que te dará un index diferente a -1 siempre que el `filterIdentificador` sea parte del `identificador_grupo`.
Si lo que buscas es lo que yo he entendido este `if` debería quedar tal que así:

> `if (filterIdentificador && item.identificador_grupo.toLowerCase() !== filterIdentificador.toLowerCase()){
>      return false;
>   }`

También le echaría un vistazo a los otros dos `if` para ver si necesitarías el mismo cambio en ellos (puesto que no se cual son tus requisitos para los otros dos campos del filtro)

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, exactamente era eso